# Можно ли гибернацию Windows превратить в выключение ноутбука?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Ноутбук не поддерживает WOL в полностью выключенном состоянии (техподдержка подтвердила), но может включаться, если находится в режиме гибернации. Как я понимаю, гибернация это некий гибрид сна и выключения (слепок ОЗУ лежит в системном диске), есть ли возможность сделать, чтобы при выходе из гибернации система запускалась с нуля (скажем так, чтобы слепок просто не использовался и удалялся)? Якобы ноутбук на Windows 10 выключен и включается как обычно.